# Transaction With db context in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to Commit transaction from c# context:

```
private TestDbEntities context =new TestDbEntities(ConnectionString); 

this.context.Connection.Open();
System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = this.context.Connection.BeginTransaction();
DbCommand command = this.context.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Some Insert/Update Query";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction.Commit();
```

But I get the error message:

> "The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier Table_Name, line 1,
>   column 8."

Query seems fine when I directly execute directly on sql management studio.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you please show _exact_ query that you use?

Comment: The query you are trying to exec has a syntax error near `Table_Name` as the error states

Comment: Seems pretty clear error msg to me.

Comment: Also, did you set the `DbCommand.Transaction` property?

Comment: My query is "UPDATE Users SET UserStatusId = 271, TabletDateModified = CAST('7/27/2015 4:56:38 PM' AS DATETIME), ModifiedUserId = 11187, DateDeleted = null WHERE UserId = 59085". 

It works fine when I execute on Sql Management studio

Comment: Consider putting tables which are named like keywords in parenthesis: `UPDATE [Users] SET ...`

Answer (score -2):

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(); 
 SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(); 
 SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(); 

            SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            command1.Transaction = trans;
            command2.Transaction = trans;

            try
            {
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
```

Comment: The question does not stop at the title. :) OP already has transactions in place, it's their specific query that's causing trouble.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to address the actual problem the OP is having. However, for future answers it is best if you include not just code you think will fix the problem but also some written explanation of your thinking.